# Не появляется Toast на андроид

Tags: java, android, android-toast

Я использую тосты впервые.
Приложение не падает, но тост не работает.

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnUpper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Click"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnUp;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnUp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnUpper);
    }

    public  void onClick(View view){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Это тост!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();//не работает
        btnUp.setText("clicked");//работает
    }
}
```

Возможно, эмулятор не поддерживает тосты.
Target: Android 11.0(google play)

Comment: Должно работать. Возможно, вы не переустановили приложение с новой версией кода. ПОпробуйте добавить деталей проблемы - как именно не работает, работало ли раньше, падает ли, есть ли логи падения etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запустил вашу версию кода. Эмулятор на версии API 27 - код работает. Проверьте включены ли уведомления для вашего приложения в настройках эмулятора/телефона.
Должно быть примерно так:

[image: скриншот эмулятора]

Comment: Здравствуйте, ваш совет не помог. Думаю, проблема связана с JDK. Можете, запустить мой код на своём компьютере?

Comment: У меня последняя версия андроид студио

Comment: @викторчернов сейчас запущу и отредактирую ответ

Comment: Уведомления и тосты - разные вещи.

Comment: Я перешёл на API 27, и всё заработало. Спасибо.